# CakePHP custom Validation rule checks unique field combination only on create

Tags: validation, cakephp, unique, updatemodel

I have a Database with a User model. These Users should be unique by their name and birthday. 
So I wrote a custom validation function called checkUnique

```
public function checkUnique($check){
        $condition = array(
            "User.name" => $this->data["User"]["name"],
            "User.lastname" => $this->data["User"]["lastname"],
            "User.birthday" => $this->data["User"]["birthday"]
        );

        $result = $this->find("count", array("conditions" => $condition));

        return ($result == 0);
}
```

The validation rule in the model:

```
"name" => array(
       "checkUnique" => array(
            "rule" => array("checkUnique"),
            "message" => "This User already exists.",
            "on" => "create"
       ),
)
```

I have two problems.
The first: This validation rule also triggers on update action, implemented as

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Update done.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user can't be saved.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
        }
    }
```

But I wrote `"on" => "create"`, so why it triggers also on update?
The second problem:
If the validation rule only triggers on create, how can I manage, to trigger an validation error, if someone change the name, lastname and birthday like an other user in the Database? Then the unique validation rule should be triggered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the 'on' => 'create'. (You want to validate in both events).

Modify your custom validation rule to this

```
public function checkUnique() {
    $condition = array(
        "User.name" => $this->data["User"]["name"],
        "User.lastname" => $this->data["User"]["lastname"],
        "User.birthday" => $this->data["User"]["birthday"]
    );
    if (isset($this->data["User"]["id"])) {
        $condition["User.id <>"] = $this->data["User"]["id"];
        //your query will be against id different than this one when 
        //updating 
    }
    $result = $this->find("count", array("conditions" => $condition));
    return ($result == 0);
}
```

Comment: Correction:  $condition["User.id <>"] = $this->data["User"]["id"];

Comment: may you help me here @Guillemo Mansilla  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771575/cakephp-3-2-unique-validator